# Is there anyway to export coloured dataframes in R?

Tags: r

I have a tukey results table that i would like to export while preserving the colourings :

[image]

I've tried :

```
png("test.png", height = 50*nrow(stat.test), width = 200*ncol(stat.test))
grid.table(stat.test)
dev.off()
```

but the table is saved like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. This gives negative numbers a red background and positive numbers a green background instead of the font itself.

```r
library(gt)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(
  group1 = c("Y", "1", "1", "2"),
  estimate = c(-5.8,-7, 1, 2),
  conf.low = c(-1,-10, 2, 3)
)


df |>
  gt::gt() |>
  data_color(
    columns = c(estimate, conf.low),
    colors = scales::col_bin(
      bins = c(-Inf, 0, Inf),
      palette = c("red", "green"),
    )
  ) |>
  gt::gtsave(filename = "test.png")
```

[image]

Comment: The |> pipes are getting flagged as unexpected tokens for me for some reason?

Comment: You can use `%>%` as long as install and use `library(magrittr)` or `library(dplyr)`

Comment: When running it i now get the error:    `google-chrome` and `chromium-browser` were not found. Try setting the CHROMOTE_CHROME environment variable or adding one of these executables to your PATH.
Error in initialize(...) : Invalid path to Chrome